# CMS for publishing Linked Data with the 303 URI method

Tags: linux, open-source, cms, rdf, linked-data

I’m looking for a **CMS** that allows to publish **Linked Data** (**RDF**) out of the box.

As a solution for the [httpRange-14 issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPRange-14), it MUST use the [303 URI method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-cooluris-20081203/#r303uri):

> [image: URI representing the "thing" 303-redirects, depending on content negotiation, to RDF or HTML representation]

It’s, for example, [used by the DBpedia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669):

1. The URI http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Lord_of_the_Rings (`…/resource/…`) represents the *thing*.
2. When visiting this URI, you get HTTP status code **303 See Other**.
3. Now **content negotiation** redirects you to your preferred representation, i.e.,

   1. http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Lord_of_the_Rings (`…/page/…`) if you prefer HTML
   2. http://dbpedia.org/data/The_Lord_of_the_Rings (`…/data/…`) if you prefer some RDF serialization

Bonus: Allow different RDF serializations, e.g. `/data/The_Lord_of_the_Rings.xml` (for RDF/XML), `/data/The_Lord_of_the_Rings.turtle` (for Turtle) etc. The additional serializations should, of course, be generated/converted automatically.

I have no specific requirements about how to add data.
I’d prefer a GUI that allows to enter triples, preferrably with auto-completion of internal URIs/CURIEs and external vocabularies.

The HTML representation should be auto-generated from the RDF data, allowing to browse to related documents and values of triples.

---

#### Formal requirements

- It MUST be **FLOSS**.
- It MUST run natively on a **GNU/Linux** server.

(Personally, I can’t use a Java-based solution, but please recommend them nonetheless as others might be interested.)

Answer (score 1):

If an automated system is acceptable, then [Walder](https://github.com/KNowledgeOnWebScale/walder) seems a quite decent option.

It requires Node.js (not Java).  It is Free Software (using liberal Mit/Expat license).

It does *not* provide a GUI, however - so if that is what you imply when requiring a "CMS" then unfortunately this is not adequate.